# Finding in txt specific chars by index

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with Ruby homework.

There is a txt file with 1000 chars (One per each line)
So program asks user for 9 numbers 0..999
After that it should find and print 9 chars from file

*Example output*
Give 1. number between 0-999: 444
Give 2. number between 0-999: 756
Give 3. number between 0-999: 223
Give 4. number between 0-999: 999
Give 5. number between 0-999: 0
Give 6. number between 0-999: 123
Give 7. number between 0-999: 23
Give 8. number between 0-999: 44
Give 9. number between 0-999: 533
your word is ryqbaAsQn

Here is my code

```
#coding:utf-8
path = "7-3_tiedosto.txt"
lst = Array.new 
word = Array.new
text = ""

puts "Luodaan salasana."

for i in 1..9
   print "Anna #{i}. luku väliltä 0-999: "
   lst.push(gets.to_i)
end

my = File.open(path, "r")
my.each{|line| word.push(line.chomp)}
my.close

for i in 0..8
   a = lst[i]   
   text = text << word[a]
end

puts "Ohjelma loi salasanan #{text}"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: It gives error in the last for loop,
like word array contains nil

So what is the way to get specific lines from the txt and why
array "word" may contain nil??

Comment: +1 for confessing it is homework

Comment: I solve the problem by .join the "word" array and then .split that again,
but I think it's kinda stupid way to do....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a good opportunity to familiarize yourself with ruby debugging. Issues like these arise when your program state is different than expected. It's up to you to figure out why state is different than you expect and then take corrective action.

I'd recommend trying either 1) using put statements to print out program state while your program is executing or 2) use the ruby debugger to step through your program as it is running to verify state.

Here's a primer on debugging: http://ruby.about.com/od/advancedruby/a/debugging.htm

Hope that helps! These kinds of issues come up all the time, so it's important to learn how to approach them. Best of luck.